# Error parsing manifest when deploying to Azure kubernetes

Tags: azure, kubernetes, github-actions

I'm setting up a GitHub action for deploying to Azure kubernetes. The deploy job looks as follows:

```
deploy:
    name: Deploy to kubernetes
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: docker
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Setup kubectl
        uses: Azure/setup-kubectl@v3
      - name: Setup cluster context
        uses: Azure/k8s-set-context@v3
        with:
          method: kubeconfig
          kubeconfig: ${{ secrets.AZURE_K8_KUBECONFIG }}
      - name: Deploy to Azure
        uses: Azure/k8s-deploy@v4
        with:
          manifests: manifests/test/manifest.yml
          images: ghcr.io/${{ env.image_name }}:${{ needs.release-on-push.outputs.version }}
          pull-images: false
          annotate-namespace: false
```

When it gets to the deploy phase it runs through a manifest, which looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: localizer
spec:
  selector:
    app: localizer
  ports:
    - name: std-api-ports
      port: 8080
      targetPort: http-in

---

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: localizer
  labels:
    app: localizer
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTP"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "300M"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx-default
  rules:
    - host: localizer.UUID.LOCATION.aksapp.io
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: localizer
                port:
                  name: std-api-ports
            path: /
            pathType: Prefix

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: localizer
  labels:
    app: localizer
    domain: frontend
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: localizer
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 0
      maxSurge: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: localizer
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: localizer
          image: ghcr.io/urltorepo
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 0.5
              memory: 2G
            limits:
              memory: 2G
          ports:
            - name: http-in
              containerPort: 8080
          env:
            - name: NODE_ENV
              value: "test"
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /ping
              port: http-in
            failureThreshold: 3
            periodSeconds: 30
          startupProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /ping
              port: http-in
            failureThreshold: 12
            periodSeconds: 10
```

The workflow then fails due to an error which is as follows:

```
Run Azure/k8s-deploy@v4
  with:
    manifests: manifests/test/manifest.yml
    images: ghcr.io/***/localizer:
    pull-images: false
    annotate-namespace: false
    namespace: default
    strategy: basic
    route-method: service
    version-switch-buffer: 0
    traffic-split-method: pod
    percentage: 0
    action: deploy
    force: false
    token: ***
    private-cluster: false
    skip-tls-verify: false
  env:
    image_name: ***/localizer
    AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME: localizer-app
    KUBECONFIG: /home/runner/work/_temp/kubeconfig_1682630327009
Deploying manifests
  /opt/hostedtoolcache/kubectl/1.27.1/x64/kubectl apply -f /tmp/manifest.yml --namespace default
  service/localizer unchanged
  ingress.networking.k8s.io/localizer configured
  error: error parsing /tmp/manifest.yml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 25: mapping values are not allowed in this context
  Error: Error: undefined
```

From the console it would seem that the Service is setup and the Ingress is setup, which leads me to believe that the Deployment is the one with the error. I've run the manifest through a YAML validator and it passes. I've tried commenting out values from the manifest, hence the console showing that the Service is unchanged and Ingress is configured instead of created. I seem to be blind as to what the error could be now.

UPDATE:
I've now tried to split the manifest file into three files(Deployment, Ingress and Service). This has allowed me to figure out that it definitely is the Deployment manifest that is causing the error. I've also found that the error is related to "image" element. I've tried to follow a course from Microsoft on Azure kubernetes and if I change out my image with the one in the example, then there isn't a problem.

Comment: `- host: localizer.UUID.LOCATION.aksapp.io` this needs to be all lowercase according to RFC standards. Is that a filler for the SO question or are you actually doing it like this?

Comment: It's a filler, location is all lowercase and uuid is lowercase letters and numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the action not working, then I decided to try to write the manifests directly in Azure through the Cloud Shell. The manifests worked as intended which resulted in the understanding that the problem is related to the Deploy action. Finally running the action with debugger activated, the problem finally exposed itself. The image wasn't receiving the version from an earlier job. This resulted in the image being displayed as "ghcr.io/*****/****:". This was then perceived as an object in the Deployment.yml